# Bootstrap 5 with Grunt to bundle and optimise js

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bootstrap-5

I have successfully used Grunt to bundle the bootstrap 5 scss together into a single file. I have it setup so I can add and remove the component scss to the needs of the project for optimisation.

I am now trying to do the same with the js.

I am using grunt-contrib-uglify with the following task:

```js
uglify: {
    site: {
        options: {
            sourcemap: false
        },
        files: {
            'example/static/example/assets/js/example.min.js': [

                // popper bs5 dependency
                'node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.js',

                // bootstrap 5 core js
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/data.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/event-handler.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/manipulator.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dom/selector-engine.js',

                // component js
                // note ordering of components can be important
                // eg. popover relies on tooltip, therefore tooltip must therefore go first
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/base-component.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/alert.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/button.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/carousel.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/collapse.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/offcanvas.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/scrollspy.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tab.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/toast.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/tooltip.js',
                'node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist/popover.js',

                // custom js
                'example/src/js/**/*.js'
            ]
        }
    },
},
```

I include it in my html, then have a script below it eg.

```
<script>
    var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasExample')
    var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
</script>
```

I get the error:

**ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined**

in the console. What am I missing from the bundle to make this work? I have used the npm bs5 starter on Github as a reference for the files eg. popper dependency, the core js and imported all other component files in the node_modules/bootstrap/js/dist folder.

[Github Bootstrap 5 npm starter](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-npm-starter/blob/v5/assets/js/starter.js)

Bootstrap 5.1

Popper 2.9.2

Edit: Works correctly with distributed bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so using the same grunt uglify task above, you can:

```
<script>
    var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasExample')
    var bsOffcanvas = Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)
</script>
```

(Note the removal of *new bootstrap.* from the script). I think this is because when importing the component files separately you are not importing Bootstrap as a module. Therefore unlike the bundle it is not available.

However, the components as separate functions are imported and available (much like Offcanvas in the above example)

**EDIT**

As bootstrap 5 uses rollup to bundle its javascript I have now looked into the 'grunt-rollup' task. I was not happy in the respect that my previous answer did not align with the bootstrap docs.

I have since got it working successfully with the grunt-rollup task with this configuration:

```
// gruntfile imports
const babel = require("@rollup/plugin-babel").default;
const path = require('path')
const {nodeResolve} = require("@rollup/plugin-node-resolve");

// rollup task
rollup: {
    options: {
        plugins: [
            babel({
                exclude: './node_modules/**',
                babelHelpers: 'bundled',
            }),
            nodeResolve()
        ],
        globals: {
            '@popperjs/core': 'Popper'
        },
        external: ['@popperjs/core'],
        format: 'umd',
        name: 'bootstrap',
    },
    files: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, `path/to/bootstrap5/imports/file`),
        dest: path.resolve(__dirname, `path/to/export/file`),
    },
},
```

where the bootstrap imports file looks like:

```
import Alert from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/alert'
import Button from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/button'
import Carousel from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/carousel'
import Collapse from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/collapse'
import Dropdown from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/dropdown'
import Modal from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/modal'
import Offcanvas from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/offcanvas'
import Popover from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/popover'
import ScrollSpy from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/scrollspy'
import Tab from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/tab'
import Toast from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/toast'
import Tooltip from 'node_modules/bootstrap/js/src/tooltip'

export default {
  Alert,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  Collapse,
  Dropdown,
  Modal,
  Offcanvas,
  Popover,
  ScrollSpy,
  Tab,
  Toast,
  Tooltip
}
```

now you can choose which components to have in the js.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a super expert and not sure if the question is clear enough, but I would not recommend concatenating Libraries like Boostrap into a single main file in together other JS files outside the framework, due to performance issues and possible crashes in between libs due to definitions, and the possibility to update without a build process and also your site might be penalized by google engine.

Besides that, Boostrap normally already provides `.min.css` and `.min.js` already compressed/minified/uglified ready to use if you are not gonna change anything from the original design patterns, avoid using uncompress files if you are not gonna customize it.

for the rest in regards to other custom libraries or vanilla's JS create by you, you can use [grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) also if you wanna check the performance you can use
[PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=en) with the result will know what exactly needs to be applied to get better performance and optimization.

Comment: it is more a question with the optimisation of the bootstrap js using Grunt I suppose, sorry for not being clear. There is a page on general optimisation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/ but was wondering how this is possible with Grunt.